# Google Fit wait for multiple results

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm using Google Fit history client to read multiple data types from user:

```
historyClient.readDailyTotal(TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
historyClient.readDailyTotal(TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
historyClient.readDailyTotal(TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
```

Each call has its own success/failure callback (`addOnFailureListener`, `addOnSuccessListener`).
How can I "group" this call and wait to have ALL data available? Shoul I use an asynctask or what? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the readData method of the fitness history client.

This exemple may help you:

```
val startTime = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        time = Date()
        add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1)
    }.timeInMillis

val endTime = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        time = Date()
    }.timeInMillis

historyClient.readData(DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .read(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
        .read(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
        .setTimeRange(
            startTime,
            endTime,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
        )
        .bucketByTime(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .enableServerQueries()
        .build()
    )
```